# Resolve method name from string defined in object

Tags: typescript

There is an object that defines some strings

```
static readonly COMPARISON_OPERATORS = {
  [QueryObject.EQUALS]: "equals",
  [QueryObject.NOTEQUALS]: "notequals",
  ...
}
```

Then I'm trying to call some methods on another object `c`

```
c[QueryObject.COMPARISON_OPERATORS[operator]].apply(c, args);
```

And I'm getting the all famous "Element implicitly has any type". I tried to cast it to avoid the error

```
(<() => {}>(<any> c)[
   QueryObject.COMPARISON_OPERATORS[operator]
]).apply(c, args);
```

I haven't used ts in a while and my casting skills are probably way off. How do I need to cast this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some type information to your `COMPARISON_OPERATORS` declaration.

Assuming your keys (and values) while be of type `string`, you can do something like this to keep the object literal syntax:

```
static readonly COMPARISON_OPERATORS: {[key: string]: string;} = {
    "=": "equals",
    "!=": "notequals",
    //...
}
```

Secondly, you're trying to define the properties of your object with dynamic keys.  This cannot be done while defining an object literal.

To use dynamic keys, you need to declare an object then add keys manually:

```
const myObject: {[key: string]: string;} = {};
myObject[QueryObject.EQUALS] = "equals";
// ...etc.
```

Comment: I just added the type definition and that solved it. It does not seem to complain about the dynamic keys, they will probably get transpiled automatically. I believe that's valid es6 syntax anyway.